# How do I add a video to a view controller in XCode 8?

Tags: ios, video

I am building an app that shows pre-recorded videos of animals in nature.   These videos are brought in as assets, not from a link online.  Which video is played depends on the user selection (for example, selecting "Great Horned Owl" in the table view controller will play the video named "greatHornedOwl.mp4".  I want to create a view controller that will show the selected video.  How do I implement the video player so that it plays the correct video?

Comment: Use an `AVPlayerViewController`

Answer (score 0):

You could have seperate view contoller for playing video and one view contoller for showing list of videos, that view contoller should have table view, for table view data user some array: [String: String], i first store title for table view and in second store file name, expample:

```
var array: [String: String] = []

// add item to array
array["Great Horned Owl"] = GreatHornedOwl.mp4

var nameOfMp4File = array["Great Horned Owl"]
```